# Dotnet core 2.0 Build & Publishing couldn't be hosted in IIS

Tags: windows, jenkins, .net-core, command-prompt

I am using the command prompt to build & publish a dotnet core 2.0 project using the following method and it runs just fine without any errors but still, it is failing to be hosted anywhere.

dotnet publish  -c Release -r win10-x64 -o

Error :

Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=2.0.3.0,

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception

The same project works fine on a different machine using the same method.

Comment: You are using FDD approach, so anywhere else you need to install the runtime to host it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: try installing [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) on your windows server.